# Как подключиться из C# к другому .NET процессу?

Tags: c#, .net, отладка, reverse-engineering, декомпиляция

Как средствами C# подключиться к другому процессу и мониторить некоторые данные из него? Известно, что исследуемое приложение так же написано на .NET, при необходимости декомпилируется с помощью JetBrains dotPeek.
Знаю, что можно работать с адресами, забив на то, что проект .NET, но хотелось бы использовать более удобные методы, обращаясь к значениям по именам свойств классов, отсюда и вопрос. Возможно это что-то вроде собственного отладчика получается, как в студии, только без временной остановки процесса.

Comment: Если бы это был например стандартный PE то можно было бы вычислить смещение и попытаться достать данные из памяти и воссоздать в вашей программе структуру с данными и потом уже с ней работать, а тут скорее всего так не получится. Отладчик студии не даст вам отлаживать что то без исходников, по этому тут аналогия не совсем уместна. Студия отладку ведет по исходникам.

Comment: Посмотрите Windbg.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, но ведь можно дебажить в студии декомпилированные проекты, если тот же JetBrains dotPeek сгенерит файлы символов вместе с исходниками. Ну и вот всё дело как раз в том, что не хотелось бы вычислять смещения и всё такое. Ведь студия же как-то это делает без гемора, значит можно и самому так. Вот только как?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, используя [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime](https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd). Впрочем, запросы у вас слишком велики: получить значения свойств без приостановки процесса (т.е. в пассивном режиме отладки) невозможно. Свойства - это, в конце концов, те же методы. Получить значение поля в пассивном режиме, конечно, можно. Например, следующий код демонстрирует присоединение к процессу в пассивном режиме, поиск в его управляемой куче объекта определенного типа и получение значения его поля:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {       

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTarget dt=DataTarget.AttachToProcess(17680,5000,AttachFlag.Passive); 

            using (dt)
            {
                ClrInfo runtimeInfo = dt.ClrVersions[0];
                ClrRuntime runtime = runtimeInfo.CreateRuntime();

                ClrType type;

                foreach (ulong obj in runtime.Heap.EnumerateObjectAddresses())
                {
                    type = runtime.Heap.GetObjectType(obj);

                    if (type == null) continue;

                    if (type.Name == "System.Windows.Forms.Form" || 
                        (type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.Name == "System.Windows.Forms.Form"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Address 0x{0:X}: {1}", obj, type.Name);
                        ClrInstanceField f = type.GetFieldByName("Foo");
                        object val = f.GetValue(obj);
                        if (val != null) Console.WriteLine(val.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    } 

}
```

**Примечание.** Пример рассчитан на ClrMD v1.X. Во [второй версии](https://github.com/microsoft/clrmd/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes2.0.md) некоторые используемые API могли быть изменены.

Comment: Вот, вот что-то такое я и хотел! Спасибо большое!)