# Поиск структуры или класса в .Net процессе

Tags: c#, memory-management

создал специально отдельный проект (scanme), в котором есть класс:

```
public class Player
{
    public int Health = 400;
    public int Mana = 15;
    public int speed = 0;
}
```

и другой проект, который должен находить к примеру переменную Health в scanme проекте.
используя функции из kernel32.dll (OpenProcess,ReadProcessMemory,GetSystemInfo,VirtualQueryEx) я нахожу адрес этой переменной.

теперь суть вопроса : требуется на основе полученного адреса переменной получить полный класс в который входит эта переменная т.е. с именами, структурой, адресами и типами.

приложение которое ищет на c# и приложение в котором ищем тоже на c# написано.
Программа Cheat Engine умеет это делать, вот для наглядности скриншот того что я нажимаю и какой получаю результат.
[image: скриншот-пример]

Предполагаю что нужно смотреть в Vtable, но её тоже нужно найти и как в ней найти имена переменных пока не понял ( если конечно она их содержит)

а на этом скриншоте то что у меня пока-что вышло ..
[image: пример]

Comment: поиск ведётся в запущенном процессе ..

Comment: Вот честно вам скажу, я заинтересован подобными вопросами и знаю намного глубже, чем ваша задача, и потому заявляю вам, что ответы на ваш вопрос легко нагугливаются.

Comment: @dmtr ткните носом хотя бы направление куда искать, я не против искать, только я уже не первый раз подобный вопрос задаю, и не выходит у меня найти, я уже и в исходники cheat engine лез .. там на delphi написано (хотя это наверное не важно .. )

Comment: @dmtr есть функция Marshal.PtrToStructure, но она же получает структуру во первых уже зная указатель на неё саму, и во вторых надо иметь определение структуры уже..

Comment: @dmtr можно просто inject нуть библиотекой dll и из неё запустить assembly reflection, но я не думаю что это лучший вариант..

Comment: "*используя функции из kernel32.dll*" - этими функциями искать класс в .NET процессе - это все равно, что искать иголку в стоге сена. Попробуйте что-то более высокоуровневое, например ClrMD: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/976435/240512

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight в том то и суть что должно быть изначально не известно к какому именно классу принадлежит найденная переменная ( она находится очень просто в два поиска.. первый находится одно значение, второй остается только нужное из найденных...)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight то на что вы кинули ссылку - довольно интересно и возможно с помощью него можно всё таки сделать, отпишу что у меня выйдет, когда изучу что эта библиотека может по моей задаче

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight используя предложенное вами у меня получилось выполнить поставленную задачу, но интересно возможно можно как-то оптимизировать или исполнить иначе .. если есть идеи, то прошу предложить

Comment: @GetYouFun насчет оптимизировать глобально не знаю, ClrMD ищет медленно, даже в пустом процессе есть много стандартных объектов и их всех нужно обходить. Но по мелочи, например, вместо проверки по сравнению имени `type.Name == "Free"` можно попробовать делать `type.IsFree`.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight у меня получилось сильно ускорить поиск, в ответе ниже привёл свои изменения - они банальные, по этому прошу посмотреть возможно я допустил какую-то ошибку, или что то не учёл ..

Comment: Я не знаю, гарантирует ли библиотека, что EnumerateObjects возвращает объекты в порядке возрастания адреса. Там документация довольно отрывочная. Если гарантирует, то ваш способ выглядит правильно, если нет, то нужно сначала сохранить адреса в List и отсортировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используя библиотеку **Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime** из ссылки предложенной **MSDN.WhiteKnight** в комментариях, вот что у меня вышло:

```
            IntPtr adrr = results[0].backadr; //сюда попадает адрес найденной переменной.
            string name = "";
            using (DataTarget dt = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(ProcId, false))
            {
                ClrInfo runtimeInfo = dt.ClrVersions[0];
                ClrRuntime runtime = runtimeInfo.CreateRuntime();

                ClrType type;
                bool found = false;
                foreach (ulong obj in runtime.Heap.GetSegmentByAddress((ulong)(adrr)).EnumerateObjects())
                {
                    type = runtime.Heap.GetObjectType(obj);
                    name= type.Name;
                    if (type == null || type.IsFree || type.IsInterface
                         || name.Contains("System") || name.Contains("CppImplementationDetails")
                         || name.Contains("Microsoft.Win32") || name.Contains("MS.Utility")
                         || name.Contains("MS.Win32") || name.Contains("MS.Internal")) continue; // исключаю объекты которых много находит в сегменте и они явно не нужны (чтобы не проверять лишний раз их поля ..)
                    foreach (ClrInstanceField cf in type.Fields)
                    {
                        if ( cf.GetAddress(obj) == (ulong)(adrr))
                        {
                            string s = ""; // если адрес поля текущего объекта равен тому на основе которого ищем -  мы нашли нужный объект и может получить остальные поля..
                            foreach (ClrInstanceField cf2 in type.Fields)
                            {
                                s += cf2.Name + Environment.NewLine;
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine(s);
                            MessageBox.Show(s);
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }


                    }
                    if (found) break;                        
                }

            }
```

В итоге удаётся найти в каком классе состоит переменная и получить все другие переменный класса, но при этом приходится проверять все объекты внутри сегмента который содержит нужный объект .. возможно это можно как то улучшить ? ограничить и в каком то приделе искать ..
А так в итоге находит примерно за ~1-2 секунды, при учёте что ищет в проекте где нечего больше и нету..

**UPD 1** Добавил классы которые исключаю из поиска для более быстрого поиска ( хотя всё равно 1-2 секунды ..  на целевом файле где уже не только один класс находит примерно за 11 секунд , это вполне нормально, хотя Cheat Engine всё равно быстрее) если бы была ещё возможность указать что вот не весь сегмент проверять, а только который сам укажешь относительно нужного адреса ..
**UPD 2**
можно заменить блок поиска вот так:

```
            IEnumerable<ClrObject> segment = runtime.Heap.GetSegmentByAddress(adrr).EnumerateObjects();
            ulong prevobj = segment.First();
            foreach (ulong obj in segment)
            {
                if (obj >= adrr) // если текущий объект находится дальше нужной переменной то мы нашли нужный класс в переменной prevobj
                {
                    found = true;
                    type = runtime.Heap.GetObjectType(prevobj);
                    // здесь уже работа с классом
                    break;
                }
                else prevobj = obj;
            }
```

таким образом ищет за 1-2 секунда в целевом процессе и находит.
не знаю возможно в этом есть какие-то минусы?